# Colorizing text in Rmarkdown fails: color-text.lua doesn't work in RevealJS

Tags: html, lua, r-markdown, reveal.js

I'm trying to make `revealjs` slides via `r-markdown`. Also, I would like to colorize some texts with an simple notation (i.e. markdown-like notation) using `lua` filter as suggested in 
[Using a Pandoc Lua filter](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/font-color.html#using-a-pandoc-lua-filter) of *R Markdown Cookbook*.

However, the produced slides are not colorized. In the following slide, the word *red* should be red and *blue* should be blue, but they don't actually.

[image]

Furthermore, the simple notation `[blue]{color="blue"}`, for instance, is unexpectedly converted into `<span color="blue">blue</span>`, not into the desirable HTML code `<span style="color: blue;">blue</span>`.

Does anybody can tell me what I am missing...?

````
---
title: "title"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2:
    base_format: "function(..., number_sections) revealjs::revealjs_presentation(...)"
    theme: moon
    pandoc_args: 
      - "--lua-filter=color-text.lua"
    transition: default
    background_transition: zoom
    center: true
    incremental: true
    number_sections: true
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
    fig_caption: TRUE
    #dev: cairo_pdf
    self_contained: false
    reveal_plugins: ["zoom", "notes", "menu"] #"search"
    reveal_options:
      slideNumber: true
      previewLinks: true
      margin: 0.1
      menu:
        numbers: true
always_allow_html: yes
link-citations: yes
---

## First

we define a Lua filter and write it to
the file `color-text.lua`.

```{cat, engine.opts = list(file = "color-text.lua")}
Span = function(span)
  color = span.attributes['color']
  -- if no color attribute, return unchange
  if color == nil then return span end

  -- tranform to <span style="color: red;"></span>
  if FORMAT:match 'html' then
    -- remove color attributes
    span.attributes['color'] = nil
    -- use style attribute instead
    span.attributes['style'] = 'color: ' .. color .. ';'
    -- return full span element
    return span
  elseif FORMAT:match 'latex' then
    -- remove color attributes
    span.attributes['color'] = nil
    -- encapsulate in latex code
    table.insert(
      span.content, 1,
      pandoc.RawInline('latex', '\\textcolor{'..color..'}{')
    )
    table.insert(
      span.content,
      pandoc.RawInline('latex', '}')
    )
    -- returns only span content
    return span.content
  else
    -- for other format return unchanged
    return span
  end
end
```

Now we can test the filter with some text in brackets with
the `color` attribute, e.g.,

> Roses are [red and **bold**]{color="red"} and
> violets are [blue]{color="blue"}.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, I can and you too: your question has the answer already.
You are

> trying to make revealjs

Therefore, when you run your code, your `lua` filter is not producing anything interesting, simply executing `return span` in the penultimate line and not the desired change.

Therefore, a simple change is your fix.
Replace:
`if FORMAT:match 'html' then`
with
`if FORMAT:match 'html' or FORMAT:match 'revealjs' then`
Doing so, the `lua` filter does its job and I get the desired output, with the proper format.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my late reply. Your solution does work! I up-voted and accepted your answer!